# Fltk1.1 with MinGw?

Tags: windows-7, mingw, mingw32, fltk

I have a project that compiles in linux and I am now trying to compile it under MinGw in Windows 7. The project includes the fltk library. When I try to compile, I get the message that the FL/Fl.h file is not found -

```
GUIWindow.h:5:18: fatal error: FL/Fl.H: No such file or directory 
compilation terminated
```

I downloaded the fltk 1.1 files and extracted them to my desktop. I went into the directory, configured, and compiled the files successfully. So what am I missing here to get this to install? I thought that with #include<>, if the library is installed correctly that it will find the files no matter where they are at. So what else is necessary under MinGw? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay well I just cut the FL folder from the fltk folder and put it in MinGw/include. This compiles. If anyone can explain why just having #include  works in linux but not in MinGw, I would be grateful.

Comment: The compiler does need to know where your header files are. It normally looks in specific directories defined at compilation in addition to core directories defined in your compiler configuration files. It sounds like there's some differences in the configuration of your compiler in linux and your compiler in MinGw, which is no surprise really :) 

 In moving the header file into your MinGw/include directory you're dropping them into the pre-configured path, hence the compiler finding them.